# Commentbox in Spotify

Tags: comments, spotify

I'm working on an app for Spotify and I want to add a commentbox to it. I've tried to use Disqus and the Facebook Commentbox, but both methods weren't succesful. Now I know this should be possible, because the app Sounddrop has a chatbox. Any ideas on adding a commentbox?

Answer (score 1):

I am writing a chat server now, and have written it all from scratch with the server in Python using the Brubeck framework. It basically involves the following.

1. Create your own server to manage saving and publishing the comments.
2. Make sure you have your URL in the Spotify manifest to allow communication to your own external server.
3. Have the Spotify app chat client communicate with your server with a long polling technique to allow real time updates.

I have the following code on github, but it is still a work in progress. It should give you an idea of what needs to be done:

https://github.com/sethmurphy/Spotichat
https://github.com/sethmurphy/Spotichat-Server

I have tried to get Disqus to work also, and in theory it should if you have development mode flag set (in Disqus); it ended with being able to connect to the server, but a javascript error was thrown and none of the comments would load.

If you haven't added the URLs you need to communicate with in the manifest then you might give Facebook a try first before writing a server and client from scratch. Look at the network tab in the inspector to see if any connections are failing and add the domains for those to the manifest.